# How to access Tomcat Server from another device using computer name instead of IP address?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, server, ip

when i access my web app from another device in the same LAN using IP address (http://192.168.x.x:8080/app_name/) it works but when i use computer name instead of IP address (http://host_computer_name:8080/app_name/)i am getting an error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
 I can't use IP address as i have dynamic IP addressing  how can i solve this issue 
 any help is highly  appreciated.

Comment: You need to learn some computer network basics (in this case DNS) in you want to write a web app.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer eventually needs to resolve the hostname to the IP address. Setting a hostname on the server doesn't mean it is propagated to the whole world.  This is a job of the DNS, effectively it translates the hostnames to the IP address.

Dynamic IP address on the servers is generally a problem. The server needs to propagate its current IP address to the DNS system. It is called 'DynDNS' and some routers are capable of the DDNS (see [list of the routers](http://dyn.com/remote-access/))

There are a few public services allowing use of the Dynamic DNS (DynDNS, NOIP.com, ...).

If you're on LAN (as you claim), most of the router can be set to force a static IP address for specific computers.

Answer (score 0):

try editing hosts file in your computer. More info : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/